# while loop in C with nested scanf

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

What's problem with the following code?  Why after I input c, the program will output "please choose the command: " twice?  And why if I input i first, then input e, the program will not output "you choose e"

```
#include <stdio.h>

void interface(){
char command;
printf("please choose the command: \n");
scanf("%c",&command);
if (command == 'c'){
    printf("you choose c\n");
}
else if (command == 'i'){
        printf("you choose i, what is next?: \n");
        scanf("%c",&command);
        if (command == 'e'){
            printf("you choose e\n");
        }
}
else if (command == 'p'){
        printf("you choose p, what is next?: \n");
        scanf("%c",&command);
        if (command == 'a'){
            printf("you choose a\n");
        }
}
}



int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    while(1){
        interface();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
...
scanf(" %c", &command);
...
```

The problem is that you have a `\n` (newline character) sitting in your input buffer and you need to clear it so your loop doesn't run again without input.

Comment: thanks! But why adding a space before %c will work in this case?

Comment: @jitron it works because when you type a command into your interface you are *not* just typing `e`, but you are actually typing `e\n` since you need to hit enter for it to register the command. So, you need to add a space before your `%c` in `scanf` to clear the `\n` from the previous command.

Answer (score 1):

just put a white space

```
scanf(" %c",&command);
```